# How to initiatialize an object according to the varying input?

Tags: java, json, list, parsing

Let me explain it through pseudocode. This is a code I am writing at my work computer that I can't take back home and there are a lot of other dependencies so I can't reproduce the same environment here on my personal pc and that's why writing pseudocode here.

```
Class Document { 
//Has some properties 
//Getter setter methods 
}

Class InputParser{ 
    public List<Documents> initializeDocuments(Json input) {

    /*
    In here, I will have to parse the Json input into the List of Document class and 
    then initialize all the items on that list.

    The initialization can be based on 2 scenarios:

    1. If the Json input doesn't contain any object of Document class, the initialize 
    function should create a document object and initialize it with default values 
    using the below function (which is clear to me) and add that object to the list 
    and return the list.

    2. But if the Json input contains one or more objects of Document class with some 
    attributes already defined and some attributes that need to be defined by default 
    values (keeping in mind to not override the attributes which are already defined 
    with default values and only initialize those attributes which are null/empty in 
    the input. So, what's the most suitable,efficient and beautiful way to do it?

    */ 
}

private Document initializeWithDefaultValues (Document document) { 
        //Initialization of default values will be here. 
} 
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a simple hashmap of similar which you can store any valid attributes and then pass the map to the `initializeWithDefaultValues` method that will use those values from the Json data rather than the defaults. Alternatly create a default document then insert the changed attributes afterwards.

Comment: I get what you're saying but can you please write a code or pseudo-code to elaborate the approach you're suggesting? And what do you think is the best approach to do it? I mean yeah i was thinking about initializing with default and then overriding it with the values provided in json but i think there is a better way to do it and that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't know what `Document` is or how it functions, so any pseudocode would just say exactly what I had in my comment. The only real way to do this more smoothly is if `Document` has a constructor method that allows you to set attributes, otherwise you need to store the byte objects of the Document instead of Json data, so no parsing is required.